# How to loop my django template from my dynamic forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I got Forms.py something like this, I make dynamic for HomeTeam until LigaTeam.

```
class CreateEvents(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        choices = kwargs.pop('choices')
        team = kwargs.pop('team')
        choicesAgent = [("%s" % x['_id'], "%s" % x['name']+" by: "+x['agentName']) for x in choices]
        teams = [("%s" % x['_id'], "%s" % x['name']) for x in team]
        super(CreateEvents,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['agent'].choices = choicesAgent
        # List Match Make Dynamic
        for i in range(0, 6):
            self.fields["homeTeam%d" % i] = forms.ChoiceField(label="Home Team %d" % (i+1), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': "form-control"}), required=True)
            self.fields["homeTeam%d" % i].choices = teams
            self.fields["awayTeam%d" % i] = forms.ChoiceField(label="Home Away %d" % (i+1), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': "form-control"}), required=True)
            self.fields["awayTeam%d" % i].choices = teams
            self.fields["matchDate%d" % i] = forms.DateField(label="Match Date %d" % (i+1), initial=DateNow(4), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Input Match Date %d' % (i+1),'class': "form-control"}), required=True)
            self.fields["matchTime%d" % i] = forms.TimeField(label="Match Time %d" % (i+1), initial=TimeNow(), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Input Match Time %d' % (i+1),'class': "form-control"}), required=True)
            self.fields["ligaName%d" % i] = forms.CharField(label="League Name %d" % (i+1), max_length = 30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Input League Name %d' % (i+1),'class': "form-control"}), required=True)

    # Event Detail
    agent = forms.ChoiceField(label="Agent", widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': "form-control"}), required=True)
    eventName = forms.CharField(label="Event Name", max_length = 30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Input Event Name','class': "form-control"}), required=True)
    startDate = forms.DateField(label="Start Date", initial=DateNow(), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Input Start Date','class': "form-control"}), required=True)
    deadlineDate = forms.DateField(label="Deadline Date", initial=DateNow(4), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Input Deadline Date','class': "form-control"}), required=True)
    endDate = forms.DateField(label="End Date", initial=DateNow(10), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Input End Date','class': "form-control"}), required=True)
    startTime = forms.TimeField(label="Start Time", initial=TimeNow(), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Input Start Time','class': "form-control"}), required=True)
    deadlineTime = forms.TimeField(label="Deadline Time", initial=TimeNow(), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Input Deadline Time','class': "form-control"}), required=True)
    endTime = forms.TimeField(label="End Time", initial=TimeNow(), widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Input End Time','class': "form-control"}), required=True)
```

And I got confused how I can loop this on my template.html? is there any way to join / concat i to variable name? homeTeam+i become homeTeam0.

```
{% for i in range %}
<div class="item form-group">
    <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 label-align" for="{{ form.homeTeam0.id_for_label }}">
        {{ form.homeTeam0.label }} <span class="required">*</span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
        {{ form.homeTeam0 }}
    </div>
</div>
...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already did it Long time ago.

1. Make new function for holding variable (you call it on template)
2. Loop self.fields
3. Use if to take variable name what you will use

In this case I can match with 3 letter from front or just check if variable end with number is you want take all of it.

```
def match_fields(self):
    for name in self.fields:
        if name[0:3] == "lig" or name[0:3] == "mat" or name[0:3] == "hom" or name[0:3] == "awa":
            yield(self[name])
```

or

```
def match_fields(self):
    for name in self.fields:
        if name[-1].isdigit():
            yield(self[name])
```